# css position is not working for sticky

Tags: html, css

I have used overflow: hidden in the css file.
I am new to css and web development.
So i want to know how to use sticky on that navigation bar.
when i remove the overflow property the background changes.
Here is my code for the following.
If you can give me the code to solve that problem it will be a great help.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
legend,
label,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
footer,
figure,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%
}

.left_header a {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
  float: left;
}

.right_header {
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: right;
  padding: 12px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 30px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>The Only One Stop for Laptops &amp; their Accessories!</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
  <style>
    .content {
      height: 700px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="font-family: verdana;">

  <header class="header">
    <div class="left_header">
      <h1><b><i><a href="index.html">TechTops</a></i></b></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right_header">
      The Only One Stop for Laptops &amp; their Accessories!
    </div>
  </header>

  <br>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">

  </div>

  <hr>

  <footer class="footer">

  </footer>

  <hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try This

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,
code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,
fieldset,form,legend,label,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,
figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,footer,figure,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{
    display: block;
}

.header {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%
}
.left_header a {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
    float: left;
}
.right_header {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: right;
    padding: 12px;
}
.navbar {   
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
ul:after{ content: ""; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; clear: both; display: block; }
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
.footer {
    height: 200px;
}
```